# making a function in bash script containg awk

Tags: bash

this AWK works totally fine , but when I enclose it in a function, it causes an error in bash, is there a solution to this problem ?

```
 ps -auxh | awk '{
   tcpu +=$3
   tmm+=$4
} 
END{
        print "Total memory usage: " tmm " % Total cpu usage: " tcpu "%"
      }'
function calCPUusage{
       ps -auxh | awk '{
   tcpu +=$3
   tmm+=$4
} 
END{
        print "Total memory usage: " tmm " % Total cpu usage: " tcpu "%"
      }'
 }
 calCPUusage
```

The syntax error is test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `ps'
test.sh: line 4:`ps -auxh | awk '{

Comment: It would help if you show the function you are defining, how you call it, and exactly what error that produces.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax of creating a function. Use:

```
function calCPUusage() {
```

Comment: The parentheses are optional if you use the `function` keyword. A space is required between the name of the function and the opening `{`, though.